# ASP.NET MVC 4 Code First Many to Many Adding to Collection

Tags: collections, asp.net-mvc-4, many-to-many, addition, code-first

I am using ASP.NET MVC 4 code first pattern for database layer. I have a many to many relationship between UserProfile and Task. When I try to add a task to the the collection of tasks of a user, it's added but if I try to query it and see if it's there it's not showing up.

My model:

```
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string SirName { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TaskModels> Tasks {get; set; }
    public bool? isActive { get; set; }

    public UserProfile()
    {
        Tasks = new HashSet<TaskModels>();
    }
}

public class TaskModels
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
    public ICollection<UserProfile> Employees { get; set; }
    public int TimeNeeded { get; set; }
    public int TimeWorked { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public bool isActive { get; set; }

    public TaskModels()
    {
        Employees = new HashSet<UserProfile>();
    }
}

public class WorkLogModels
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public UserProfile Author { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeBeganWorking { get; set; }
    public int TimeWorkedOn { get; set; }
    public TaskModels Task { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

public class TimeTrackerDb : DbContext
    {
        public TimeTrackerDb() : base("DefaultConnection")
        {

```
    }

    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TaskModels> Tasks { get; set; }
    public DbSet<WorkLogModels> WorkLogs { get; set; }
}
```

I try to check if a UserProfile already exists in a Task's Employees list and it's always empty.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(WorkLogModels worklogmodels)
    {
        var tasks = db.Tasks.Where(x => x.Name == worklogmodels.Task.Name).SingleOrDefault();
        if (tasks == null)
        {
            return View(worklogmodels);
        }
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = db.UserProfiles.Where(x => x.UserId == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId).FirstOrDefault();
            var task = db.Tasks.Where(x => x.Name == worklogmodels.Task.Name).FirstOrDefault();
            WorkLogModels log = new WorkLogModels();
            log.Description = worklogmodels.Description;
            log.TimeBeganWorking = worklogmodels.TimeBeganWorking;
            log.TimeWorkedOn = worklogmodels.TimeWorkedOn;
            log.Author = user;
            log.Task = task;
            db.WorkLogs.Add(log);

            if (!db.UserProfiles.Where(x => x.UserId == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId).First().Tasks.Any(x=> x.Name == worklogmodels.Task.Name))
            {
                db.UserProfiles.Where(x => x.UserId == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId).FirstOrDefault().Tasks.Add(task);
                db.Tasks.Where(x => x.Name == worklogmodels.Task.Name).FirstOrDefault().Employees.Add(user);
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(worklogmodels);
    }
```

I've been fighting with this for two days now.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

**EDIT:**

I am not sure if I made myself clear. In the Crate action for the WorkLog Controller I am trying to put the current user in the current task's collection and vice versa. It works correctly the first time, but then if I do it again it fails to skip the if statement and tries to add it once again and throws an exception : System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException. It's trying to add the same record to the intermediate table.